# Fitting fractions of multivariate polynomial

Tags: r, regression, nls, non-linear-regression

How to fit the multivariate fractional polynomial of the following form:

Given a function: `y = f(x,z)`, a function of two variables `x` and `z`. More specifically it is of the form:

```
y = (x^2 + x^3)/(z^2 + z^3)
```

Numerator is a polynomial of a 3rd degree of a predictor x, and the denominator is also a polynomial of a 3rd degree of some predictor z.

I would like to fit polynomials for each of the predictor `x` and `z`, i.e. I need to find the coefficients A,B,C,D:

```
y = (A*x^2 + B*x^3)/(C*z^2 + D*z^3)
```

Basically, `y` is a ratio of two polynomials of degree 3. How to fit such a function?

Sample of a data frame below.
I cannot post full data frame as it has more than 1000 rows.

```
y = c(-4.10594369806545, -4.23691458506868, -4.24690667936422, -3.53677470254628, -4.30406509320417, -4.19442802077908, -4.66857169733859, -2.82271310942235, -4.19720194766181, 3.52164353473802, -4.3917019001973, -5.41654474791269, 2.87471821731616, -3.85922481986118, -4.25370811223789, -3.57887855889961, -5.33913936106829, -4.11775265312012, -2.89958841300109, -4.18661983833127)

x = c(8.06526520889773, 9.39897529082673,9.07348918922699,7.5522372875608, 9.17294998275762,5.77455154554441, 9.2005930205213, 8.07309119969315, 7.42177579364465,8.18896686364888, 8.07868822922987, 8.50956416425175,9.71269017726113, 7.98378106897745, 7.69893619981345, 8.49576524400262, 8.02224091680654,8.25400859056484, 7.58171964012531, 8.35655484545343)

z = c(2.56494935746154, 4.99043258677874, 4.43081679884331,3.66356164612965,4.53259949315326,1.79175946922805,4.23410650459726, 5.38449506278909,3.13549421592915,4.34380542185368, 3.43398720448515,2.77258872223978,6.94985645500077,3.97029191355212, 3.40119738166216,4.39444915467244,2.19722457733622,3.91202300542815,4.06044301054642, 3.87120101090789)

dat = data.frame(cbind(y=y,x=x,z=z))
```

**UPDATE:**

Call to `nls`:

```
nls(y~(a*(x**2) + b*(x**3))/(c*(z**2) + d*(z**3)), dat, start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1))
```

Comment: With my extended dataset of more than 10^3 rows, I see the error I have just posted. With the sample that I provided here, I also get gradient problem.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I still get the parameter initialization error for y and z.

Comment: Did you go through the iterations of parameters? How did you get C=10?

Comment: I can, however, find the best model by swiping through the parameters space and calculate the R^2 and other model goodness metrics. Do you think this can be the way to find the correct parameters?

Comment: I think it whould be better to use `optim()` additionaly.  `abc.f <- function(par) sum(((par[1]*x**2 + par[2]*x**3) / (par[3]*z**2 + z**3) - y)^2); optim(par=c(1, 1, -7), fn = abc.f, control=list(maxit = 1e+4, reltol=1e-12))` (example)

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice problem that you have here. At least I learned some things from it. However, I have a feeling that this question resloves more around the solution of this specific task (university assignment?) than to be a general question.

But let me share an approach to the solution:
What we have here

[image: eq1]

can be simplyfied to

[image]

Solving to y^\theta becomes numerically more managable.
As we may see (and after trying very hard and failing to solve a non linear problem) it is actually a division of two linear models. So one approach is to estimate coefficients of the two problems separately. That is we fix coefficients `a` and `b` to find `c` and `d` and afterwards use `c` and `d` to find `a` and `b`.

Following code solves for coefficients

First some data

```
library(dplyr)

sampleData <- data.frame(x = runif(100, -100, 100), z = runif(100, -100, 100)) %>%
  mutate(y = ( (-2 * x^2) + (5 * x^3) ) /  (-4 * z^2 + 6 * z^3)) %>%
  mutate(zxfactor = z^2/x^2,
         yy = y * zxfactor)
```

now we solve for `yy`. With some random starting values...

```
init2 <- structure(runif(4, -10, 10), names=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
coefab <- init2[c("A", "B")]
coefcd <- init2[c("C", "D")]
```

... we need to fit a linear model for  `a` and `b` by

[image]

and a linear model for  `c` and `d` by

[image]

```
# don't use for loop but determine a terminal condition... but i'm too lazy :-)
for(i in 1:100) {
  # make linear prediction using coeff. c and d
  sampleData <- sampleData %>%
    mutate(yab = yy * (coefcd[1] + coefcd[2] * z))
  # and fit a model for a and b
  coefab <- coef(lm(yab ~ x, sampleData))
  # then make a linear prediction using coeff. a and b
  sampleData <- sampleData %>%
    mutate(ycd = (coefab[1] + coefab[2] * x) / yy)
  # and fit a model for c and d
  coefcd <- coef(lm(ycd ~ z, sampleData))
} # repeat until satisfied

coefab
coefcd
```

Are we happy with the coefficients we have found ? Lets check:

```
optimFun <- function(params, out, x, z) {
  res <- (params[1] + params[2]*x)/(params[3] + params[4]*z)
  return( sqrt(sum( (out - res)^2 )) )
}

optimFun(c(coefab, coefcd), x = sampleData$x, z = sampleData$z, out = sampleData$yy)

> optimFun(c(coefab, coefcd), x = sampleData$x, z = sampleData$z, out = sampleData$yy)
[1] 1.951043e-12
```

Indeed we are since the difference between the modelled function estimates and data `yy` (the scaled one) is close to zero. Different iterations result in different parameter estimates since the problem is overdetermined. (Maybe someone can explain it in more detail)

---

Comments:

- The estimates are closer to zero than estimates determined by `nls`
- If you want to use `optim` you can use the `optimFun`. And for faster convergence you may even define derivate function
- Its very nice problem to show where general optimization may fail and that it is always worth it to think about the problem at hand.
- Try `lm(yyz ~ x, data = sampleData %>% mutate(yyz = yy*(-4 + 6*z)))`
   which will return exact values for `a = -2` and `b = 5`. Given any two parameters you can find a matching pair that minimizes the function.